# You have not defined a default connection

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine

How I can resolve this error?

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/connection.py", line 95, in get_connection
    raise ConnectionError(msg)
mongoengine.connection.ConnectionError: You have not defined a default connection
```

model.py:

```
from flask.ext.mongoengine import MongoEngine

db = MongoEngine()

class Currencies(db.Document):
    # meta = {"db_alias": "currencies"}
    name = db.StringField(max_length=40, min_length=3)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

MongoEngine config in app.py:

```
from models import db

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS'] = {'DB':'testing'}
db.init_app(app)
```

views.py:

```
from models import Currencies

print Currencies.objects.find()
```

Flask-Admin normally works.

Comment: Could you provide more debugging information / stack trace?

Comment: The issue is that you haven't told mongoengine which database or host to use.  I don't know Flask, but normally you can simply say `import mongoengine; mongoengine.connect('testDB', host='localhost');`

Answer (score 3):

resolve my trouble by adding 'alias' field with value 'default' to config:

```
app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS'] = {'db':'testing', 'alias':'default'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can deal this problem with setting the DEFAULT_CONNECTION_NAME in your config file like this:

`from mongoengine import connect`

`DEFAULT_CONNECTION_NAME = connect('blog')`

Comment: What config file?